Why is relative change highly correlated but absolute values for phenotype and PGS are not?
I have n "couples" (female-male pairs).
And I compute the correlation for PGS (polygenic risk score) and phenotype:
corr(PGS_female, PGS_male)
corr(phenotype_female, phenotype_male)

None of this gives a high correlation.
However corr(ΔPGS, Δphenotype) where
ΔPGS=PGS_female-PGS_male
Δphenotype=phenotype_female-phenotype_male

is actually quite high. What could this imply? That even though the traits are not strongly correlated among partners, the relationship between PGS and phenotype across couples is?

I would highly recommend plotting your data, such as with a scatterplot.

The problem is that it is difficult to see the actually couples since those are 50k pairs. Any suggestions? Sure I can see correlation of PGS with phenotype among all individuals, but I don't see the relation with the actual couples.

It's not really the individual points but the shape of the data that is useful. You could use a density plot (basically a 2D histogram) if there are too many points to render.

I think what you're probably just discovering, through, is that PGS and phenotype are correlated.

To @BryanKrause's point: try plotting PGS_female against phenotype_female and PGS_male against phenotype_male!
